# Changing Text (pre-defined) in seperate column if previous colums cell is bolded

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Doing some high quantity spreadsheet validations.  Wondering if there is a way to populate a cell in column D with a predefined text ("Enabled") if the cell next to it is bolded.  I went through and bolded them all with a duplicate conditional formatting procedure and pasted the output over to the master spreadsheet.  Now I just need a column with the text that matches so I can filter on it.  Any help would be awesome.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Which version of Excel? Is the condition formatting something that could be expressed in a formula, e.g. =if(and(cell> minimum,cell<maximum),"Enabled","")

Comment: 2010....hmm. I am not sure, I will see if that might work.  Thanks!

Comment: If it does, please comment here so that I can "answer" the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to bring up the **Name Manager**. Press **new**, name it `ifbold` and put in the **refers to** box `=if(GET.CELL(20,!$D1),"Enabled,"")`

In the column you want "enabled" to appear in for **bolded** cells, type in `=ifbold` and drag it down. It will enter "enabled" into any cell where the matching cell in column D is **bold**. If it doesn't update hit <kbd>F9</kbd>